# Tooltips in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I was wondering how I use a tooltip in react as a new user is logging into my application. I'm using react's AnT Design, I have access to two types of tooltips. However, all are only instantiated if the user makes an interaction, like a hover. I need it to be instantiated automatically when a new user is logging into the application.

Tooltip code:

```
import { Popover, Button } from 'antd';

const content = (
  <div>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Popover content={content} title="Title">
    <Button type="primary">Hover me</Button>
  </Popover>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the `defaultVisible` prop in the Popover component to true, unless you want it always visible, where the `visible` prop may become handy.